# Restore MySQL Database from another server, will it affect current databases?

Tags: mysql, sql

Morning, we have 8 databases on our live server. I have created a new one on our test/development server. In MySQL Administrator I've backed up this new database to an SQL file, this file is on the new server. If I use "restore" in MySQL Administrator to create this database, will it affect the other databases that are there or will they carry on working as normal?
Is there a better way to do this?
The new DB is only a few k in size, the others contain many years of info and data and are huge. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. As you said that your DB is small it will not affect at all the other DB. It would if it was bigger, most probably it would slow dow your server a bit during the import (if it was bigger, huge to be precise), after the import the database will work normally. Of course it will share resource to keep one more instance working. And with time, it will make some difference in performance (depending on how big this DB grow). But you will have to be more concerned with hardware capabilities then the database itself.

Of course, I assume that when you say database you are saying about a new instance on your database.